# Is there a way to aggregate multiple subgroups within a larger group/column with data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate, grouping

New R user here and I am trying to aggregate multiple groups of data within a larger group, for example Males/Females of Adults by Census Tracts. Currently I am writing it as:

```
DEmale <- DE_2016small[Gender_2016 == "M", .N, by = Residence_Addresses_CensusTract_2016] %>% rename(Males = N)
```

and a second function as:

```
DEfem <- DE_2016small[Gender_2016 == "F", .N, by = Residence_Addresses_CensusTract_2016] %>% rename(Females = N)
```

Is there any way to combine the code to find M and F as the same time, rather than as two separate commands?
The tabular data is huge, and I will need to create multiple groups more efficiently than a single command at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way based on data.table:

```
dcast(data=DE_2016small, 
      formula=Residence_Addresses_CensusTract_2016 ~ factor(Gender_2016, c("M", "F"), c("Male", "Female")), 
      fun=length)

#     Residence_Addresses_CensusTract_2016  Male Female
#  1:                                    A    19     19
#  2:                                    B    16     15
#  3:                                    C    18     25
#  4:                                    D    15     13
#  5:                                    E    22     24
#  6:                                    F    14     25
#  7:                                    G    21     22
#  8:                                    H    18     20
#  9:                                    I    20     19
# 10:                                    J    14     22
# 11:                                    K    18     22
# 12:                                    L    22     23
# 13:                                    M    20     16
# 14:                                    N    28     21
# 15:                                    O    16     17
# 16:                                    P    18     15
# 17:                                    Q    26     22
# 18:                                    R    20     22
# 19:                                    S    23     26
# 20:                                    T    18     12
# 21:                                    U    20     11
# 22:                                    V    18     18
# 23:                                    W    20     22
# 24:                                    X    21     14
# 25:                                    Y    24     12
# 26:                                    Z    17     17
```

### data

```
set.seed(123)
DE_2016small = data.table(Gender_2016=sample(c('M','F'),1000,replace=T),Residence_Addresses_CensusTract_2016=sample(LETTERS,1000,replace=T))
```

Comment: Very helpful!!  This method worked and achieved what I needed.  I also added in a few more variables after 'Residence_Addresses_CensusTract_2016' to maintain some elements after the aggregation.  Thank you!